# Substracting string arrays in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, subtraction

I've got two string arrays (s1 and s2) which are loaded from a .txt file

1.txt

```
a
c
e
```

2.txt

```
b
d
e
```

using

```
f = File.new(path, "r") #1.txt or 2.txt is passed in path
while (l = f.gets)
  res << l.chomp.downcase #just to be in the same case
end
f.close
```

I expect that `s1 - s2` should return `["a", "c"]`
BUT
I get `["b", "d", "e"]`

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Can you show us the exact code you are using for s1-s2? (it could be a minor typo or something, but we can't tell unless you show us :) (and I ask because I ran that code and it works perfectly for me)

Comment: Either both files have same content or you are putting contents of 2.txt in s1 and s2 both.

Comment: It seems likely that the bug is in code you haven't shown here.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
# this reads out all the lines into the array-variable
# (no need for open/close/gets)
s1 = File.readlines("1.txt")
s2 = File.readlines("2.txt")

# now you want to chomp and downcase each one
# (the ! is important here or you lose the changes)
s1.map!{|l| l.chomp.downcase }
s2.map!{|l| l.chomp.downcase }

# now you can do a diff
s1 - s2
```

results in: `["a", "c"]`

But please: still show us the code that you wrote so that we can figure out what the mistake was - otherwise you'll never learn ;)